# Objective-c Проиграть анимацию

Tags: анимация, objective-c, ios

Доброе время суток, в общем мне поставили задачу: нужно проиграть анимацию/остановить/проиграть с места остановки - в зависимости от событий, я вообще не в зуб ногой, ранее с анимацией не работал, что вообще нужно для того что бы всё заработало? Может есть где какая-то библиотека?
-Самое главное, в какой формате должна быть анимация? На сколько я знаю флеш iOS не поддерживает. Буду прям очень-очень благодарен за помощь, готов даже очков накинуть за правильный совет :)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала расскажите что вы будете анимировать?

Вообще в айоси 2 штатных способа анимации - через группу [методов UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131)  и с помощью [CoreAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Первое гораздо проще в реализации, но этим способом можно анимировать гораздо меньше параметров и изменяются они фактически по прямой, единственное чем можно управлять это скорость. Второе сложнее, но и более гибкое, запросто можно сделать чтобы чтобы картинка из точки а в точку б шла по спирали за счет указания ключевых кадров (первым способом что-то подобное тоже можно провернуть, но придется фактически делать много-много мелких анимаций). Приостановить и запустить снова можно тоже только с помощью Core Animation, хотя я если честно никогда этого и не делал.

Comment: @aknew, Анимация следующего рода, это не большая игра, в которой едет 2 машины и потом одна вырывается вперед.

Comment: Тогда мой ответ пожалуй не в тему - этими способами анимируют стандартные компоненты. Вам скорее всего понадобятся спрайты, попробуйте посмотреть что-нибудь типа [cocos2d][1], также обратите внимание на ответ Bimawa

[1]: http://cocos2d.org/

Comment: В его ответе способ не один из самых лучших, на ролике анимация проигрывается за счёт картинок, которые последовательно меняют, мне нужно что бы анимация была одним файлом, которою можно проиграть/остановить, не подскажете какой формат анимации должен быть?

Comment: Я ссылку на spritekit имел ввиду. В том виде в котором вы описываете я ответа не знаю, частично потому что не понимаю зачем вам это и что вы собственно хотите засунуть в файл - вектор или набор картинок.

Comment: Это игровая анимация, длительность 12 секунд, есть файл, в формате .swf но я знаю что флеш iOS не поддерживает, но файл можно переконвиртировать, вопрос только в какой формат, и как её потом запустить?

Answer (score 0):

Для .gif анимации можете попробовать [это](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/).

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView` может на вход принимать несколько картинок в виде массива `animationImages`. И перебирать их при помощи методов:

```
Animating Images
   animationImages  property
   highlightedAnimationImages  property
   animationDuration  property
   animationRepeatCount  property
– startAnimating
– stopAnimating
– isAnimating
```

Для более крутых парней: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tO4qzbQswIE